# WD mybook Windows with Mac partition over the top. Is the windows information lost?

Tags: windows, mac, partitioning, external-hard-drive

This is the worst technological day of my life, First my macbooks harddrive crashes. I try to use my friends Windows formatted hard drive (1.1TB used of 2TB) to make a mac partition to backup an image of my Mac Data. The hard drive is damaged so I need to take it to be serviced and may have lost all my Data.
We then looked at the hard drive back on my friends PC and all his info is gone too? Dear God, this is bad. We ran a partition recovery software buy this came up with nothing. What can we do from here? 
We would really love any info on this or possible solutions. Thanks a lot.
Flynn

Answer (score 0):

if it were me, and its not, I would remove the hard drive from the enclosure, connect it directly to a PC motherboard, then use [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to attempt recovery of the Windows partition.

The reason you remove it from the enclosure is to remove the usb controller from the equation when trying to recover partitions/data, a usb controller interprets commands to the disk, which you don't want when in this type of situation.

Do plenty of reading about testdisk before you use it, it is not for the inexperienced, but is very good at recovery of data.